# Calculate vector of dot products

Tags: pytorch, dot-product, tensordot

how do i do the following dot product preferably using pytorch tensordot()

Let say i have vector A and vector B :

```
[a1,a2] . [b1,b2,b3] =
```

I want to get as a result :

```
[
  a1 * b1 + a2 * b1,

  a1 * b2 + a2 * b2,

  a1 * b3 + a2 * b3
]
```

vector by vector = vector of dot products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Einsum might be handy:

```
torch.einsum('i,j->j', torch.Tensor(a), torch.Tensor(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below converts vector to matrix multiplication and sums all the values in one row.

```py
import torch
tensor1 = torch.tensor([1,2]).unsqueeze(0)
tensor2 = torch.tensor([3,4,5]).unsqueeze(0)

result = torch.sum(tensor2.t() @ tensor1, dim=1)
print(result)
```

result:

```py
tensor([ 9, 12, 15])
```